# does UITableViewController have special behavior when being popped off a UINavigationController stack?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios4

I've got a bizarre what-seems-like-a-over-release issue in a tab bar application.  My advance apologies for the complexity of this problem description.  Hopefully a little example code will help.

I have my application delegate `MyAppDelegate` set up as the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllerIn shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarControllerIn didSelectViewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)viewController;
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

The tab bar view is set up with a `UINavigationController` for each of 5 tabs.  The root view controller (call it `CrashingViewController`) in the `UINavigationController` configured for tab 4 is derived from `UIViewController` and conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols to support a `UITableView` subview, which is just a 4-row table, each cell of which allowing the user to navigate to another view.  In `-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ASubViewController1 *svc1;
    ASubViewController2 *svc2;  // this one inherits from UITableViewController;
    ASubViewController3 *svc3;
    ASubViewController4 *svc4;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
            svc1 = [[ASubViewController1 alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc1 animated:YES];
            [svc1 release];
            break;
        case 2:
            svc2 = [[ASubViewController2 alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc2 animated:YES];
            [svc2 release];  // if I comment this out, I avoid the problem described
            break;
        /* case 3 and 4 are exactly like the previous two */
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

What happens is this: if the user selects the 4th tab of the tab bar, the `CrashingViewController`'s view is displayed.  Then, the user taps the second cell in its table, which pushes an instance of `ASubViewController2` onto the navigation stack.  So far so good.  Now, if the user taps another tab on the tab bar, another view controller's view is presented.  If the user then taps the 4th tab again, the `UINavigationController` configured as the root view controller for that tab pops all its items and is supposed to show *its* root view controller.  It's during this that the app crashes, as the UIKit framework somewhere along the way calls [ASubViewController2 respondsToSelector:] on `svc2` after it has already been freed.

The thing that I'm having a hard time with is this: why is this crash occurring when the user navigates to `ASubViewController2`, but none of the other `ASubViewController*`s?  Also, if I fail to release `svc2`, the crash doesn't occur - so it's definitely a double release on `svc2` somewhere, I just don't know where that's happening.  `svc2` is a method-local variable and I release it right after allocating it.  Does a `UITableViewController` somehow act differently when being popped off a navigation controller's stack than does a `UIViewController`?  Am I missing something else?

I'm sure I'm just missing something that's well-documented or otherwise straight-forward, but I've been looking at it long enough to have some blind spots in place.

**update**:

I do have NSZombiesEnabled.  here's the message given in the console:

```
*** -[ASubViewController2 respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe345cd0
```

And the backtrace:

```
#0  0x02a18fa7 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x02a18e72 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x003e69be in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _spacingForExtraSeparators] ()
#3  0x003ede94 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _adjustExtraSeparators] ()
#4  0x003e6743 in -[UITableView layoutSubviews] ()
#5  0x027b9481 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#6  0x027b91b1 in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#7  0x027b22e0 in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#8  0x027b2040 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#9  0x027e2ebb in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#10 0x02a88f4b in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x02a1db27 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#12 0x029e6ce7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x029e6350 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x029e6271 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x0329200c in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x032920d1 in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x00380af2 in UIApplicationMain ()
#18 0x0000226a in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffef64) at ~/main.m:16
```

**update 2**:

The `dealloc` method of `ASubViewController2` is called on `svc2` after the user taps tab 4 the second time and before the zombie message is output.  None of my code is in the code path for the dealloc.

Comment: which selector is called on ASubViewController2? This looks like a complicated problem:)

Comment: Sounds like over-releasing problem to me. Could you show us the code for ASubViewController2, both .h and .m?

Comment: I don't know.  I haven't been able to get any of the `_NSZombie` breakpoints to resolve.  Yeah....it seems complicated to me as well because.

Comment: I can't show you the entire code because it's for a client :-(, but I could mock an example.  Alternatively, if you could tell me what you'd be looking for, I could tell you what's there.

Comment: If I were you, I would inspect about how I handle the table view delegate calls, IBOutlets and init and dealloc. I strongly believe there is over-releasing somewhere in the code.

Comment: @tia: you're absolutely right - what's difficult is that there's a dealloc being called on `svc2` somewhere in the callstack kicked off by the user tapping the 4th tab for the second time.  It's all in UIKit.  It's also confusing that this doesn't happen to the other subviews that inherit from UIViewController, which are all set up in the same way.  You're right to suggest the delegates and outlets, though.  I'll certainly revisit all that.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention, but it might be the case of under-releasing too. From the stack trace, it is possible that your views are still there but your view controller has gone, so when your table view needs something, it calls delegate that has been deallocated. Albeit the code inspection process is somewhat similar, but make sure you release all of your retained views and subviews ;).

Comment: I'd say the same: seems like you accidentally retained the `UITableView` in `svc2` and didn't release it accordingly...

Comment: ah.  yes - that seems a bit obvious to me now that you mention it (it always works that way, you know).  I noticed that in ASubViewController's `dealloc`, only `[super dealloc]` was being called and that was it.  For some reason, I didn't connect the dots between that and the problem I was having.  I'll check that.

Comment: Ah, I think this has something to do with the fact that `ASubViewController` gets deallocated before it is sent the message `viewDidUnload`, which would account for the UITableView still being there but the delegate being gone.  I still don't understand why it would be in the callstack, though.  In any case @tia, if you'll put this in an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: If you use non-property `IBOutlet`, it will be retained at loading time, so you should release it in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`. Please also be aware that `viewDidUnload` will be invoked only in certain case (e.g. memory warning received), so you cannot rely solely on `viewDidUnload` to release your variables. For me I always write `releaseOutlets` method and call it from `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`. After all it is hard to imagine without real source code, but I hope it would work eventually ;).

Answer (score 5):

I encountered similar problem. It seems that view controller already freed but its table view still calls the delegate that is freed view controller. Simply add the following or similar lines in view controller's dealloc:

self.tableView.delegate = nil;
self.tableView.dataSource = nil;

It helps for me!